# Datetime picker c# Blazor

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I use c#, in Blazor WebAssembly.
I want to use a Datetime picker to take the selected date and time as input from the user. I want him to see only the data available from the backend (including the date and including the time). That is, if he wants to make an appointment on 04.05.2023 at 14:00, and there is an available appointment from the backend, he cannot see that time.
Currently I used a datetimepicker from syncfusion but it does not work on the backend connection side. Can you help me with some examples?
I tried like this:

```
<EditForm class="d-flex flex-column align-items-left" Model="@newAppointment" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <FluentValidationValidator />
    <div class="w-25 p-3">
        <label for="id" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Dentist: </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <InputSelect class="form-select" id="id" ValueExpression="@( () => newAppointment.DentistId)"
                                            Value="@newAppointment.DentistId"
                         ValueChanged="@( (Guid value) => {newAppointment.DentistId=value;HandleDentistApp(value);})">
                @foreach (var dentist in dentists)
                {
                    <option value="@dentist.Id">@dentist.FirstName @dentist.LastName</option>
                }
            </InputSelect>
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => newAppointment.DentistId)" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <Syncfusion.Blazor.Calendars.SfDateTimePicker TValue="DateTime?" Min='@MinDate' Max='@MaxDate' @bind-Value='@newAppointment.dateTime'
                                                  StrictMode=true Placeholder="Select a date and time" 
                                                  ShowTodayButton="true" 
                                                  ShowClearButton="true">
                                                  <DateTimePickerEvents TValue="DateTime?" OnRenderDayCell="@onRenderDayCellHandler"></DateTimePickerEvents>
                                                  <ValidationMessage For="@(() => newAppointment.dateTime)"/>
    </Syncfusion.Blazor.Calendars.SfDateTimePicker>
    <br />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create appointment</button>
</EditForm>

    private List<DentistResponseModel> dentists = new List<DentistResponseModel>();

    private List<DateTime> appointmentsSelectedDentist = new List<DateTime>();
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var tempDentistsList = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<ApiResult<IEnumerable<DentistResponseModel>>>("api/Dentists/all");
        dentists = tempDentistsList.Result.ToList();

    }

    protected async Task HandleDentistApp(Guid dentistIdSelected)
    {
        //checked
        var stringDentistIdSelected = dentistIdSelected.ToString();
        var tempAppointmentsSelectedDentist = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<ApiResult<IEnumerable<AppointmentResponse>>>($"api/Appointment/allapp/dentist{stringDentistIdSelected}");
        foreach (var item in tempAppointmentsSelectedDentist.Result.ToList())
        {
            appointmentsSelectedDentist.Add(item.dateTime);
        }

    }

    private RequestAppointment newAppointment = new RequestAppointment
        {
            CustomerId = Guid.Parse("c210cc12-7484-41b9-96da-834d2faf3aa2") // by default an ID customer. Need to be current Id customer
        };

    private string response = string.Empty;

    public DateTime MinDate { get; set; } = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).Day, 02, 00, 00);
    public DateTime MaxDate { get; set; } = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.AddYears(2).Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 25, 12, 00, 00);
    public DateTime? DateValue { get; set; } = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 10);

    public void onRenderDayCellHandler(RenderDayCellEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Date.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Saturday" || args.Date.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Sunday")
        {
            args.IsDisabled = true;
        }
        //implement only dentist available dates
        foreach (var appRegister in appointmentsSelectedDentist)
        {
            if (appRegister.Date.DayOfYear == args.Date.DayOfYear)
            {
                if (appRegister.Date.TimeOfDay == args.Date.TimeOfDay)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(appRegister.Date + " first IF: arg.date is " + args.Date);
                    args.IsDisabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        bool confirmed = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("confirm", "Are you sure?"); // Confirm
        if (confirmed)
        {
            var request = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/Appointment", newAppointment);
            this.response = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        }
        else
        {
            NavManager.NavigateTo(Routes.Index);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How many appointsments are we talking about? Maybe two InputSelect will do what you want. First select contains all dates and the second one all the times based on the selected date.

Comment: I want user to make a single appointment that will contain date and time. Do you have a solution?

Comment: Try `foreach (var appRegister in appointmentsSelectedDentist)
    {
        if (appRegister.Equals(args.Date))
        {
            args.IsDisabled = true;
            break;
        }
    }`